# Arch Linux sudden wifi lag

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwlwifi

Today I've encountered a really strange wifi bug. Basically, everything is running fine until I get really non-responsive internet. The wifi icon in gnome shows 'connected', but Chrome does not load pages and just times out.

Next time this happened, I ran a ping to google DNS and got really long response times, like 30000 ms range. I decided to leave ping running while I work. Suddenly, this happened:

[image]

I checked `journalctl` - nothing. My OS is Arch Linux, `uname -a`:

```
Linux 4.4.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 10 07:38:19 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Laptop is Dell Latitude e7450 with an Intel wifi card.

```
lspci
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)

lsmod | grep 'wifi'
iwlwifi               163840  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              483328  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

Any idea what may cause this and how to debug it?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. paste the *actual text* (or, in this case, a smal sample of it). Also, how do you manage your connection?

Comment: Sorry about image, I'll edit it when I'll be on my PC. I use Gnome and it's front-end for NetworkManager.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be resolved after changing my wifi rotuer from 11bgn mode to 11bg.